# Hibernate changes my original query

Tags: mysql, sql, jakarta-ee

Following is sub part of my original query (notice parenthesis):

```
( applNm IN ('TT','AA') AND typeCd IN ('H') ) OR  ( applNm IN ('PP') AND typeCd IN ('R') )
```

and what hibernate creates it:

```
(APPL_NM in ('TT' , 'AA')) and (TYPE_CD in ('H')) or (APPL_NM in ('PP')) and (TYPE_CD in ('R'))
```

Hibernate adds more parenthesis, which changes the sense of my query. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
((APPL_NM in ('TT' , 'AA')) and (TYPE_CD in ('H'))) or ((APPL_NM in ('PP')) and (TYPE_CD in ('R')))
```

I think hibernate have standards queries this is why it change the original query

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I have tried your approach too, but still hibernate is resulting the same. My query is auto-generated, and my code gives me proper result but hibernate modifies it.